# View: *.xhtml not found in component

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a popup log.xhtml that polls the server to show the content of a file, interacting with one componente called logTailer.

The following message is being written every 2 seconds to the log:

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(WARN 1), summary=(View: log.xhtml not found in component), detail=(View: log.xhtml not found in component)]
```

I guess I can add `<h:messages>` to show the actual error, but why is it happening?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollToBottom(elemId) {
        var textarea = document.getElementById(elemId);
        textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
    }
</script>

<rich:tabPanel width="100%" height="100%">
    <rich:tab label="XStreamlineapp">
        <h:form id="logForm" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <a:poll id="appPoll" interval="4000"
                enabled="#{logTailer.appPollEnabled}" reRender="logTail,logTailSum"
                oncomplete="scrollToBottom('logForm:logTail');" />
            <s:div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText id="logTailSum"
                        value="#{sl:formatString(messages['logPopup.summary'],logTailer.appLogTail[1],logTailer.appLogTail[2])}"
                        styleClass="dr-tbpnl-cntnt" style="border:none" />
                    <a:commandLink id="appControl" reRender="appPoll,appControl">
                        <h:graphicImage
                            value="#{logTailer.appPollEnabled ? '/icons/control_pause.png' : '/icons/control_play.png'}"
                            title="#{logTailer.appPollEnabled ? messages['logPopup.pause'] : messages['logPopup.play']}"
                            style="vertical-align:middle;" />
                        <a:actionparam name="polling"
                            value="#{not logTailer.appPollEnabled}"
                            assignTo="#{logTailer.appPollEnabled}" />
                    </a:commandLink>
                    <h:graphicImage value="/icons/email.png"
                        title="#{messages['logPopup.email']}"
                        onclick="populateEmailBody('','logForm:logTail')"
                        style="vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:inputTextarea
                    style="border: 3px solid #cccccc; width: 100%; height: 96%;"
                    id="logTail" value="#{logTailer.appLogTail[0]}" readonly="true" />
            </s:div>
        </h:form>
    </rich:tab>

    <rich:tab label="XStreamlinedata">
        <h:form id="logDataForm" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <a:poll id="dataPoll" interval="4000" enabled="true"
                reRender="logDataTail,logDataTailSum"
                oncomplete="scrollToBottom('logDataForm:logDataTail');" />
            <s:div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText id="logDataTailSum"
                        value="#{sl:formatString(messages['logPopup.summary'],logTailer.dataLogTail[1],logTailer.dataLogTail[2])}"
                        styleClass="dr-tbpnl-cntnt" style="border:none" />
                    <a:commandLink id="dataControl" reRender="dataPoll,dataControl">
                        <h:graphicImage
                            value="#{logTailer.dataPollEnabled ? '/icons/control_pause.png' : '/icons/control_play.png'}"
                            title="#{logTailer.dataPollEnabled ? messages['logPopup.pause'] : messages['logPopup.play']}"
                            style="vertical-align:middle;" />
                        <a:actionparam name="dataPolling"
                            value="#{not logTailer.dataPollEnabled}"
                            assignTo="#{logTailer.dataPollEnabled}" />
                    </a:commandLink>
                    <h:graphicImage value="/icons/email.png"
                        title="#{messages['logPopup.email']}"
                        onclick="populateEmailBody('','logDataForm:logDataTail')"
                        style="vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:inputTextarea
                    style="border: 3px solid #cccccc; width: 100%; height: 98%;"
                    id="logDataTail" value="#{logTailer.dataLogTail[0]}"
                    readonly="true" />
            </s:div>
        </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

There are a lot of facelets templates involved. This is the one that has the link to open the popup. Is this because I should have both templates in the same view?

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich"
xmlns:a="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:sl="http://volantice.com/streamline">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openLogPopup(){
        h = jQuery(document).height();
        w = jQuery(document).width();
        l = w/2;
        t = 0;
        window.open('/studio/admin/log.seam', 'LogTailer', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, ' + 'width=' + w/2 + ', height=' + h/2 + ', left=' + l + 'top=' + t);
    }
</script>

<s:div id="header" style="#{headerStyle}">

    <h:form prependId="false">

        <s:div id="banner">

            <s:div id="loginStatus" style="float: right">

                <sl:ajaxStatus />

                <sl:languageMenu />

                <sl:processAreaMenu />

                <c:if test="#{identity.isLoggedIn(false) and (not param.embedded)}">
                    <sl:logoutMenu />
                    <sl:zoneMenu />
                    <sl:zoneSearch />
                </c:if>

                <h:outputLink onclick="openLogPopup(); return false;" value="#"
                    rendered="#{s:hasRole('Developer') or s:hasRole('Administrator')}">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/icons/bug.png"
                        title="#{messages['logPopup.open']}"
                        alt="#{messages['logPopup.open']}"
                        style="vertical-align:middle; margin-top:3px;" />
                </h:outputLink>

            </s:div>

        </s:div>

        <c:if test="#{not param.embedded}">
            <sl:zonePages />
        </c:if>
    </h:form>
</s:div>
```

Comment: Are you sure your log.xhtml view is in the same location as the current view you're at?

Comment: Apart from that, I'm not seeing where you're referencing it in the code. Also, the code contains a lot of noise, making it much harder to spot the cause. Please try to post code in SSCCE flavor.

Comment: I added the xhtml that opens the pop up. Do you see anything wrong?